# How to make some text red in mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

Which tags or mediawiki markup symbols should I use to make some text of red or any other color?

Comment: see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Formatting#HTML_tags

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I doubt this belongs to StackOverflow. In my humble opinion it belongs to the web apps StackExchange site (don't remember the name) unless you are trying to do it programmatically.

Anyway, you can do it by using span as in following example:

```
<span style="color:red">red</span>
```

You can also set the background as follows:

```
<span style="background:red">red</span>
```

Comment: Why aren't wiki markup languages considered relevant here?

Comment: see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Formatting#HTML_tags